# extract substring from mysql column using regex

Tags: mysql, regex, substring

My regex is

```
(pnr|(P|p)[ _.:,!"'-/$](N|n)[ _.:,!"'-/$](R|r))+[ _.:,!"'-/$]+[0-9]{3}[ _.:,!"'-/$]+[0-9]{7}
```

It is extracting pnr number from column .

sample text :

```
94eb2c0cb17ef354bb052c57f40c\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding pnr:986-097832

94eb2c0cb17ef354bb052c57f40c\r\nContent-Type: pnr:986-097832 text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding 

pnr:986-097832 94eb2c0cb17ef354bb052c57f40c\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding
```

**I have to create a mysql query which will extract only the pnr number**

Answer (score 21):

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(column, 'pnr:[0-9\-]{10}')
FROM table
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Neat and simple.

Comment: `REGEXP_SUBSTR` only for MySQL >= 8.0 !

Answer (score 10):

Try **SUBSTRING_INDEX**

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(
SUBSTRING_INDEX('94eb2c0cb17ef354bb052c57f40c\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding pnr:986-097832', 'pnr:', -1), ' ',1);

SELECT 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(
SUBSTRING_INDEX('94eb2c0cb17ef354bb052c57f40c\r\nContent-Type: pnr:986-097832 text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding', 'pnr:', -1), ' ',1);

SELECT 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(
SUBSTRING_INDEX('pnr:986-097832 94eb2c0cb17ef354bb052c57f40c\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding', 'pnr:', -1), ' ',1);
```

**sample**

```
mysql> SELECT
    -> SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    -> SUBSTRING_INDEX('94eb2c0cb17ef354bb052c57f40c\r\nContent-Type: pnr:986-097832 text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding', 'pnr:', -1), ' ',1);
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX(
SUBSTRING_INDEX('94eb2c0cb17ef354bb052c57f40c\r\nContent-Type: pnr:986-097832 text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding', 'pnr:', -1), ' ',1) |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 986-097832                                                                                                                                                                  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> SELECT
    -> SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    -> SUBSTRING_INDEX('pnr:986-097832 94eb2c0cb17ef354bb052c57f40c\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding', 'pnr:', -1), ' ',1);
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX(
SUBSTRING_INDEX('pnr:986-097832 94eb2c0cb17ef354bb052c57f40c\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding', 'pnr:', -1), ' ',1) |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 986-097832                                                                                                                                                                  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: i'm trying to use substring_index but i have to use it with regex as pnr can be p:n:r or PNR or p.n.r : 123-3123212

Comment: @Sunil Harak - you can try to normalize "pnr" like this and put this in my query **SELECT REPLACE(
  REPLACE(
  REPLACE('pnr:986-097832 94eb2c0cb17ef354bb052c57f40c\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding'
  ,'p:n:r','PNR')
  ,'p.n.r','PNR')
  ,'pnr','PNR');**

Comment: @Sunil Harak - or if you using MariaDB you can directly use REGEXP_SUBSTR see :https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/regexp_substr/

Comment: Works in old version of Mysql (5.0.x for me) What some user might look for! (since old documentation are not online anymore)

Comment: here are for old ducu https://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-archive.html

Answer (score -8):

For Oracle we can do something like below -

```
    SQL> create table test2( id varchar2(2000));

    Table created.

    SQL> insert into test2 values ('pnr:986-097831 94eb2c0cb17ef354bb052c57f40c\r\nC
    ontent-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding');

    1 row created.

    SQL> insert into test2 values('94eb2c0cb17ef354bb052c57f40c\r\nContent-Type: pnr
    :986-097832 text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding')
      2  ;

    1 row created.

    SQL> insert into test2 values('94eb2c0cb17ef354bb052c57f40c\r\nContent-Type: tex
    t/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding pnr:986-097833');

    1 row created.

    SQL> select regexp_substr( id, '(P|p)(N|n)(R|r):[0-9]*\-[0-9]*' ) PNR FROM  test2;

    PNR
----------------

pnr:986-097831
pnr:986-097832
pnr:986-097833

    SQL>

`
```

Comment: thanks for you response :) , but i want it for mysql